# Forward declarations or self-sufficient headers?

Tags: c++, coding-style, header, include

Google's C++ style guide [says](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Header_File_Dependencies), "Don't use an #include when a forward declaration would suffice."

But [C++ Coding Standards](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm) (Sutter and Alexandrescu), item #23 is, "Make header files self-sufficient. Behave responsibly: Ensure that each header you write is compilable standalone, by having it include any headers its contents depend upon."

Which strategy is best?

Comment: I prefer googles.  It reduces complexity.

Comment: It's quite possible to do both.

Comment: I don't think they contradict each other. Applying both seems like a good idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sutter and Alexandrescu on item #22 say "Don't be over-dependent: Don't #include a definition when a forward declaration will do".

Personally, I agree with this statement. If in my class A, I don't use any functionality of a class B, nor I instantiate an object of class B, then my code doesn't need to know how class B is made. I just need to know that it exists.

Forward declaration is also useful to break cyclic dependencies...

Edit: I also like a lot the observation that Mark B pointed out: it happens sometimes that you don't include the file a.hpp because it's already included in the file b.hpp you are including, which chose to include a.hpp even though forward declaration was enough. If you stop using the functions defined in b.hpp, your code won't compile anymore. If the programmer of b.hpp had used forward declaration, that wouldn't have happened, since you would have included a.hpp somewhere else in your code...

Comment: good find! That settles the false dichotomy.

Answer (score 4):

Dependency management is very important in C++: if you change a header file, all translation units depending on this header file need to be compiled. This can be very expensive. As a result you want your header files to be minimal in the sense that they don't include anything they don't need to include. This is what Google's advice is about.

If you need a certain component, you should include the component's header. However, you should not required to include anything but the component's to *get* the declarations. That is, each header file has to compile without including anything else. This is the advice given by Herb and Andrei. Note that this **only** applies to getting the declaration: if you want to use any of these declaration and this requires another component, you might need to include the header file for this component as well.

These two advices go together, however! They are both very valuable and they shall be followed without compromise. This basically means, that you prefer to declare a class over including its header iff you only need the class declared. That is, if the class appears only declarations, in pointer or reference definitions, the parameter list, or the return type it is sufficient to have the class *declared*. If you need to know more about the class, e.g. because it is a base or a member of class being defined or an object is used e.g. in an inline function you need the *definition*. Effectively, you need the definition of the class if you need to know any of the members or about the class's size.

One interesting twist are class templates: only the first class template declaration can define default arguments! A class template can be declared multiple times, however. To make your header files minimal while declaring class template, you probably want to have special forwarding headers for the involved class templates which only declare the class template and it default arguments. However, this is way into implementation land...

Answer (score 2):

I'd say both statements are correct.  If you have a header file that contains only a pointer or a reference to some data type, then you only require a forward declaration.

If however your header contains an object of a particular type, then you should include the header where that type is defined.  The advice from Sutter and Alexandrescu is telling you not to rely on the consumers of your header to resolve such references by including the required type definitions.

You may also want to check out the [Pimpl Idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Idioms#Pointer_To_Implementation_.28pImpl.29) and [Compilation firewalls](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/024.htm) (or [C++11 version](http://herbsutter.com/2011/11/04/gotw-100-compilation-firewalls/)).

Comment: Thanks, now I see what I was missing. A header file can often compile with a forward declaration of something that isn't #include'd. Only the code file still needs the #include.

Answer (score 2):

I believe they're both saying exactly the same thing.

Suppose you have a method that takes a `Bar` by reference your your header file, but the method is defined in your source file. A forward declaration in the header is clearly sufficient for the header to compile standalone.

Now let's look at the user code. If the client is just passing around a reference that's forwarded from somewhere else, then they don't need the definition of `Bar` at all and everything is fine. If they use a `Bar` in some other way, then that source file is what's mandating the use of the include for `Bar`, *NOT* your header. And in fact, if you include the unneeded `Bar` include in your header then if a client stops needing your include and removes it, all of a sudden their other `Bar` code quits working because they never properly included it in their own source file.

Now suppose that your header uses `std::string`. In that case, in order for the header to compile standalone you must include `<string>`, which both guidelines would tell you to do (google because a forward declaration won't do, and Sutter and Alexandrescu to allow the header to compile standalone).

Answer (score 1):

Sutter and Alexandrescu are probably more correct here. If I forward declare `class Foo;` that for some reason resides in `bar.h` and do not include `bar.h`, good luck trying to find the declaration of `Foo` (especially if the code-base is large).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what's covered in the other answers, there are cases where you *must* use a forward declaration because of mutual dependences.

FWIW, if I only need a type name, I usually forward declare it. If it's a function declaration, I generally include it (though those cases are rare since non-member functions are rare and member functions must be included).

If it's an `extern "C"` function, I *never* forward declare is since the linker can't tell me if I've messed up the argument types.

Answer (score 1):

These two recommendations are *completely* compatible with each other. You can follow both of them at the same time. They are in no way mutually exclusive -- it's not an "either or" situation.

A header may use a forward declaration, when that is all that is needed, and still be compilable stand-alone:

```
// Foo.hpp
class Bar; // Forward declaration

class Foo {
public:
    void doSomethingFancy ();

private:
    Bar *bar;
};
```

In the above example, `Foo.hpp` is self-sufficient even though the `Bar` class is declared using a forward declaration rather than by inclusion of the `Bar.hpp` header.